# mysql replace values in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a users table in my mysql database with columns like id, age and gender.
I have inserted around 500 records into it.

Now i need to interchange the gender for the records, i.e., replace male with female and female with male.

I thought to do it this way:

```
update users set gender='female' where gender='male';
update users set gender='male' where gender='female';
```

But as you can see, as soon as i run the first query, all the records will be updated with the gender set to 'female'.

How can i modify the query or shall i go another way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
update users set gender=case when gender='male' then 'female' else 'male' end where gender in ('male','female');
```

Answer (score 6):

```sql
UPDATE users SET gender='tmp' WHERE gender='male';

UPDATE users SET gender='male' WHERE gender='female';

UPDATE users SET gender='female' WHERE gender='tmp';
```

Comment: This answer updates the table records multiple times, check out the other ones to do it in one go

Answer (score 3):

Combine two queries into one :-

```
update users set gender = if (gender='female', 'male', 'female');
```

Comment: assuming, you have a third gender, this could update rows, which you won't to be updated ;)

Comment: naturally this should be so ;) but there could be an 'undefined' state (if OP allows this case), when a user won't give any data about his gender (i.e. the field gender could be empty and your statement would manipulate this field). but +1 for using `IF`

Answer (score 3):

```
update users set gender='fem' where gender='male';
update users set gender='male' where gender='female';
update users set gender='female' where gender='fem';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update users set gender='wasmale' where gender='male';
update users set gender='male' where gender='female';
update users set gender='female' where gender='wasmale';
```